# Gradle provide string array as external property

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Android Gradle plugin has abiFilters method that takes array of strings like

```
 abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
```

I have Gradle extertanl properties such as

```
ext.minSdkVersion=14
ext.compileSdkVersion=25
ext.targetSdkVersion=25
ext.buildToolsVersion="25.0.2"
ext.abiFilters = "armeabi"
```

I could notfind what sort of format I should use for ext.abiFilters when I want to provide more than on abi.

I have tried many such as

```
 ext.abiFilters = "armeabi, armeabi-v7a...."
 ext.abiFilters = 'armeabi, armeabi-v7a....'
```

What would be the correct format?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In gradle.properties you can have :

```
ABI_FILTERS=x86;x86_64;armeabi;armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a
```

In build.gralde use

```
ext.abiFilters = []
ext.abiFilters.addAll(ABI_FILTERS.split(';').collect{it as String})
```

Comment: ABI_FILTERS="x86;x86_64;armeabi;armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a" gave error Error:(10, 0) Could not set unknown property 'ABI_FILTERS' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.

Comment: ext.abiFilters = []
    ext.abiFilters.addAll("x86;x86_64;armeabi;armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a".split(';').collect{it as String}) gave error 
Could not find method abiFilters() for arguments [[x86, x86_64, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a]] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.

Comment: Are you setting ABI_FILTERS in gradle.properties file

Comment: Did now and had Error:(38, 0) Could not find method abiFilters() for arguments [[x86, x86_64, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a]] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.
<

Comment: Having ABI_FILTERS in gradle.properties file is not ideal for me. I was hoping that there would be a way to keep all in one place

Comment: `ext.abiFilters = "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"` try this

Comment: I have before.     Error:(10, 0) startup failed:
build file '...build.gradle': 10: expecting '}', found ',' @ line 10, column 31.
       ext.abiFilters = "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
                                 ^

Comment: gradle version ?

Comment: version is 3.4.1

Comment: when I use `ext.abiFilters = []
ext.abiFilters.addAll(ABI_FILTERS.split(';').collect{it as String})` it not giving me any error